# excel formula, I want to know EXCEL FORMULA for multiple conditions (7 conditions)

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I have excel sheet with numeric data 15 rows and 4 columns(A,B,C,D). (Excel Image attached, in image E column and F column added for explanation only)
Required formula for following conditions.(image)

Actually formula need to apply for covering only two row if suppose required output DATA for row#3 (A3) than ONLY above row#2 (B,C,D) data needs to consider in formula, means for A3 data need to consider row#2 B2,C2,D2) for A4 data need to consider B3,C3,D3) likewise same for other rows.

A3 NOT HIGHER THAN B2 AND NOT LOWER THAN C2 "NORMAL"

A5 HIGHER THAN B4 "HIGHER"

A6 LOWER THAN B5 "LOWER"

A8 FIRST 3 DIGIT MATCH WITH C7 AND D7 "L-SIRIES"

A11 FIRST 3 DIGIT MATCH WITH B10 AND D10 "H-SERIES"

A13 FIRST 3 DIGIT MATCH WITH B12 "H-RANGE"

A14 FIRST 3 DIGIT MATCH WITH B13 "L-RANGE"

currently I tried below formulas.

> =IF(A3>B2,"HIGHER",IF(A3C3,"NORMAL",""))) 
>   (somehow after writing above formula here in BOX  <> sign not displaying once I save my edits)

I tried another for "H-RANGE" =IF(LEFT(A3,3)=LEFT(B2,3),IF(A3=B2,TRUE, FALSE),TRUE) [getting Output but result is not accurate.

I tried another for "L-RANGE" =IF(LEFT(A3,3)=LEFT(C2,3),IF(A3=C2,TRUE, FALSE),TRUE) getting result but result is not accurate.

Conditional Formatting FORMULA also fine for highlight "A" column WITH DIFFERENNT condition match color.

Thank You in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Please add the formulas that you have tried

Comment: currently I am using =IF(A3>B2,"HIGHER",IF(A3<C2,"LOWER",IF(B3<>C3,"NORMAL",""))) and getting result for "HIGHER", "LOWER" and "NORMAL" but output NORMAL is not accurate and I need help for "H-SERIES" , "H-RANGE" , "L-SERIES" , "L-RANGE"

Comment: I tried another for "H-RANGE" =IF(LEFT(A3,3)=LEFT(B2,3),IF(A3=B2,TRUE, FALSE),TRUE) [getting Output but result is not accurate.

Comment: I tried another for "L-RANGE" =IF(LEFT(A3,3)=LEFT(C2,3),IF(A3=C2,TRUE, FALSE),TRUE) getting result but result is not accurate.

Comment: You explain a lot of the conditions with terms that aren't meaningful to anyone but you.  In the 1st three, you can compare two cells, but you've added qualifiers normal, higher, and lower.  What do we do with those terms?  Similarly, the last four refer to series and ranges.  Those terms appear in col E as "explanation", but it isn't obvious what's being explained or how to use the information.  There's an indication that those are actually desired outputs, but then the conditions that produce those outputs aren't clear.  (cont'd)

Comment: Also, the rules seem to consider all of the data, rather than row-specific results, so the logic of what "results" are reported where, and in relation to what, isn't clear.  Then you ask for a single formula covering 7 conditions and it isn't clear how or where that would be applied, or how many results it is supposed to produce.  Please provide clarification in the question, itself, rather than responding in comments.

Comment: Thank You for your guide. Will TRY to modify Question with more clarification.

Comment: actually formula need to apply for covering only two row if suppose required output DATA for row#3 (A3) than only above row# 2 (B,C,D) data needs to consider, means for A3 data need to consider row#2 B2,C2,D2) for A4 data need to consider B3,C3,D3)

Comment: Edit the post & add all those Formula you have tried so far,, instead of putting as comments,,, honestly your questions needs lots of hard work and research since for every second Row,, logic changes,,, any single formula hardly could meet all such logic,, !!

Comment: Rajesh, Thanks for your feedback. Actually I do not have much knowledge about excel formula, But I tried through google search and reach to 30% stage then I stuck on my couple of logic. Even I don't know there is possibility or not ? to get the perfect result, hence I came here and asking to Expert, and I have hope someone will surely help.

Comment: @JUSTWIN,, check the post I've tried and it's working ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this Formula in Cell `AF2` & fill down.

  `=IF(AND(LEFT(AA2,3)=LEFT(AC1,3),LEFT(AA2,3)=LEFT(AD1,3)),"Lseries",IF(AND(LEFT(AA2,3)=LEFT(AB1,3),LEFT(AA2,3)=LEFT(AD1,3)),"Hseries",IF(AND(LEFT(AA2,3)=LEFT(AB1,3)),"HRange",IF(AA2>AB1,"Higher",IF(AA2<AC1,"Lower",IF(AB2<>AC1,"Normal","LRange"))))))`

**N.B.**

- Formula does't returns `LRange` for `Row 14`, because first 3 digits of the value in `AA14` doesn't matches with first 3 digits of `AB13`.
- Check values in both cells in BLUE color.

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: RAJESH SIR, Thank YOU SO MUCH for your PRECIOUS efforts.

Comment: RAJESH SIR, Thank YOU SO MUCH for your PRECIOUS efforts. There is little mismatching forrow14  LRange - but LET me try from my end with another DATA, will update you if need your help to modify in your provided formula.. Thank You Genius.

Comment: @JUSTWIN,, read the **N.B.** with my post I've described Y `Row 14` doesn't matches,, since it's check with uneven pattern so it may vary in cell/cells, depends on set or Rows !!

Comment: @ Rajesh S. Thank You SIR, Yes I noted your comment about Row 14. I am happy to inform that with your PERFECT Formula, I just made little changes now RESULT is SUPERB.. Thank you for your HELP and SUPPORT.

Comment: =IF(AND(LEFT(N4,3)=LEFT(P3,3),LEFT(N4,3)=LEFT(Q3,3)),"Lseries",IF(AND(LEFT(N4,3)=LEFT(O3,3),LEFT(N4,3)=LEFT(Q3,3)),"Hseries",IF(N4>O3,"Higher",IF(N4<P3,"Lower",IF(AND(LEFT(N4,3)=LEFT(O3,3)),"HRange",IF(AND(LEFT(N4,3)=LEFT(P3,3)),"LRange",IF(N4=O4,"Open=High","Normal")))))))

Comment: above Formula after little modification and also I have added one more condition which is also giving perfect output..Thank You ONCE AGAIN.

Comment: Nice ,, glad to help you @JUSTWIN,,, keep asking ☺

Comment: In general when handling numeric data like this I try to avoid using string functions like LEFT as they distract from the meaning of what you are doing. In this case what is really being tested is if the amount of hundreds of the value is the same, then the numbers are close enough to consider the same. (I'm guessing these are prices in pence/cents so this means if the dollar part is the same, treat them differently). So rather than LEFT(foo,3) I would use INT(foo/100) as it shows what is really happening - we are identifying values between two others which do not differ by more than a dollar.

Comment: @AdamV,, great works,, yes such changes are possible !